# Docker copy does not work with wildcards on windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run following dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /sln
COPY ./db/*/MyApp.csproj ./db/
```

It fails with message that file:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load build context
error from sender: CreateFile */MyApp.csproj: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

If I change wildcard to MyApp everything works.

Also this works even with wildcard when running on windows machine. I wonder if this is by design?

I've tried linux containers under WSL2 and HyperV.
It's easy to repro by calling commands:

```
mkdir db\MyApp
"" >> db\MyApp\MyApp.csproj
```

and running this dockerfile there.

Comment: Please copy paste the full error message into your question.

Comment: Which type of project are you using? Framework or Core?

Comment: @hamaronooo type of project does not matter, it fails even with simple files